# Logistical regression for system of coordinates

Tags: machine-learning, coordinates, logistic-regression

I am learning to apply different machine learning techniques. Now, I was recommended logistical regression for my problem, but I can't figure out how to apply it to my dataset.

I have a dataset with xyz-coordinates as a time-series, where each row contains the xyz data for one test-subject, labeled with either A or B. I would like to classify whether a new row of xyz-data would belong to condition A or condition B. Is it possible to apply logistical regression to my data, when I have to classify by looking at a time-series based set of coordinates? E.g. can I use logistical regression to predict if a set of time-series coordinates belongs to condition A or condition B?

The following array is an example, where each set of three coordinates represent the XYZ-coordinates of that time frame.

```
array([array([[array([[0.01889996]]), array([[-0.28033654]]),
    array([[1.4816033]]), array([[2]], dtype=uint8)],
   [array([[0.01381396]]), array([[-0.28270772]]),
    array([[1.50570126]]), array([[2]], dtype=uint8)]
```

Comment: How is different from general problem? You have feature `xyz` and label, now you want to predict for test `xyz`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is that the XYZ-coords are related, so I can't simply appoint A or B. I have to classify by using the set of coordinates, not individual ones.

Comment: Even features are correlated, it doesn't harm the analysis of model.

Comment: So I can just 'throw' a set of coordinates and a label in a classifier and it will work?

Comment: Okk, if you are saying, you have to use sequence of coordinates, to predict the label for last one, still it can work, but its performance will not be so good

Comment: It's not supposed to classify the last one, but I'll see if I can simply throw in an entire set (1 row) of coordinates.

Comment: i will add some method, which can be useful for this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `feature engineering` concept known as `lag-feature`, to keep sequence relation. For example, the label for coordinates will probably depend on the last or 2nd last coordinates. So you can use `2` last rows of features along with current row, with output of current row as target. This is an `efficient` method to keep such co-relation in data. Here is [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/basic-feature-engineering-time-series-data-python/) for more info.

You can also try [`recurrent-network`](https://towardsdatascience.com/recurrent-neural-networks-and-lstm-4b601dd822a5), which is another best way to keep track of `time-relation` in data.